# How does the chain edge connection works in Jaseci?

Tags: jaseci

I'm new to Jaseci  world. Here I'm trying to figure out how the chaining edge connections between nodes works in jaseci. In the following code snippet was taken from the Jaseci Bible.

```
node person;
edge friend;
edge family;

walker init {
   node1 = spawn node::person;
   node2 = spawn node::person;
   node2 <-[friend]- here -[friend]-> node1 <-[family]-> node2;
}
```

According to the bible the graph is as follows;
[image: Graph in memory for the code snippet]

The chain connection works left to right. I don't get how the line `node2 <-[friend]- here -[friend]-> node1 <-[family]-> node2;` creates the `e1` edge. Can someone help me to understand this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the diagram doesn't match the code. Must be an error in the Bible. I just plopped your code example in a file and ran it with `jsctl -m jac dot nextion.jac`. I got this output:

```
strict digraph root {
    "n0" [ label="n0:root"  ]
    "n1" [ label="n1:person"  ]
    "n2" [ label="n2:person"  ]
    "n0" -> "n1" [ label="e0:friend" ]
    "n0" -> "n2" [ label="e1:friend" ]
    "n1" -> "n2" [ label="e2:family", dir="both" ]
}
```

If you render this in graphviz online it looks like

[image: Dot output for example code]